# C function to initialize and display singly linked list giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, segmentation-fault, initialization

My function is giving a segmentation fault and I can't figure why.
If the return type of the list_initialize is List itself, it works perfectly fine. But I need the return type to be void and the program to still work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct List List;
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *link;
};

struct List {
    Node *head;
    int number_of_Nodes;
};

void list_initialize(List* ptr_list) 
{
    ptr_list = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List)); 
    (ptr_list)->head = NULL;
    (ptr_list)->number_of_Nodes = 0;
    return;
}

void list_print(List* list) 
{
    Node *p;
    p=list->head;
    if(p == NULL)
    {
        printf("EMPTY\n");
        return;
    }
    while (p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",p->data);
        p=p->link;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void main() 
{
    List *list;
    list_initialize(list);
    list_print(list);
}
```

Comment: C parameters to functions are call by value. So `list_initialize(list)` does not return a changed value of `list`. You need to pass a pointer to `list` (which is a `List **` type parameter): `list_initialize(&list)`.

Comment: You may find [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) helpful. There is no need to "initialize" the list beyond setting your pointer `NULL` initially. Then just write an `add()` function to add nodes to your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting segmentation fault at line 27 `(p = list->head;)`, trying to use a null pointer. As lurker mentioned that `list_initialize` take argument by value, therefore it has not modified its input parameter so in your `main` variable `list` always null.

Probably following code works,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct List List;
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *link;
};

struct List {
  Node *head;
  int number_of_Nodes;
};

void list_initialize(List** pptr_list)
{
  List* ptr_list = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
  (ptr_list)->head = NULL;
  (ptr_list)->number_of_Nodes = 0;
  *pptr_list = ptr_list;
  return;
}

void list_print(List* list)
{
  Node *p;
  p = list->head;
  if (p == NULL)
  {
    printf("EMPTY\n");
    return;
  }
  while (p != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d ", p->data);
    p = p->link;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
  List *list = nullptr;
  list_initialize(&list);
  list_print(list);
}
```